# Windows API for rust giving "Interface not registered" error when constructing PrintManager

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

I am attempting to use the `windows` rust crate API to print a jpeg in rust

first I import the PrintManager using `use windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintManager;`

then define the main function
`fn main() {`
and attempt to create a PrintManager using the GetForCurrentView method
`let print_manager = PrintManager::GetForCurrentView().unwrap();`
however when I run it I get the following error
`` called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { code: HRESULT(0x80040155), message: "Interface not registered" } ``

Minimally reproducible example

Cargo.toml

```
...
[dependencies.windows]
version = "0.44.0"
features = [
    "Devices_Printers",
    "Foundation",
    "Win32_Graphics_Printing",
    "Graphics_Printing"
]
```

Main Program

```rust
use windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintManager;

fn main() {
    let print_manager = PrintManager::IsSupported();
    dbg!(print_manager)
    // this is where the error gets thrown 
    let print_manager = PrintManager::GetForCurrentView().unwrap();
    dbg!(print_manager);
}
```

I expect for the function to return a PrintManager struct that I can later use to print a JPEG however it keeps throwing this interface not registered error, I have tried running the program as an administrator with no luck.

Comment: I don't think that calling `GetForCurrentView()` makes sense on a thread that doesn't own a view, window, or dispatcher. What value does `IsSupported()` return?

Comment: IsSupported() return true

Comment: You'll need a `CoreWindow` to use this API.

Comment: Are there any windows APIs that can let me print something without needed a core window?